# Is mrpt_ro_slam deprecated?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the mrpt_slam package so that I can run mrpt_ro_slam (range only slam). It looks like the package ended at Hydro (http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_ro_slam) and I have Indigo. Is the mrpt_navigation package the continuation of the mrpt_slam package? It is on Indigo and Jade (http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_navigation) and contains mrpt_localization, but it is unclear to me if it has some version of range only slam.

Basically, my question is if there is a range only slam package that has not been deprecated?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227401/is-mrpt_ro_slam-deprecated?/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2016-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

mrpt_ro_slam is now working for range only slam.

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/19003/nbanyk/) with karma: 40 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0